# cURLの-sSって何ですか？

Tags: curl

cURLのコマンドでcomposerをインストールしたくていろいろ調べていたところ、

```sh
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

というコードを見つけました。

curl まではいいとして、そのあとのオプションですが -sS というのが
なんなのかわからず調べても出てこず困っています。

どなたかご存知であれば教えていただきたいです。

Comment: [curl(1): transfer URL - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl)

Comment: metropolisさんのおっしゃるように、オンラインマニュアルを参照しましょう。ご提供のURLのサイトの該当部分は以下のとおりです。
お使いの環境にmanコマンドその他が入っていれば、man curlでも確認できます
------
-s/--silent
Silent or quiet mode. Don't show progress meter or error messages. Makes Curl mute.
-S/--show-error
When used with -s it makes curl show an error message if it fails.
-------

余分な情報は抑止するけど、失敗時のエラーメッセージは出してね。
ということです。

Comment: @ 皆さま、次回から回答はコメントではなく回答としてご投稿くださいませ。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-a` オプションと `-b`　オプションとうような1文字オプションを複数同時に指定する場合、`-ab`というようにグループ化して指定できることが多いです([参考](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02))。

それを踏まえると、今回の場合は `-s`, `-S`オプションが同時に指定されていると考えられますので、それぞれの意味を見てみます。

典型的には、`--help`オプションを付けて実行してみる、あるいはUNIX系OSでは`man curl`コマンドを実行してみることで利用方法(今回の場合オプションの説明)がわかります。
(あるいは、よく使われていそうな組み合わせであれば、web検索でキーワードとして `"curl -sS"` (ダブルクォーテーションで括るのがポイント)を指定して検索すれば解説がヒットすることも少なくないです。)

以下はオフィシャルサイトのマニュアルページリンクです。
https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-S

> -S, --show-error
>
> When used with -s, --silent, it makes curl show an error message if it
>   fails.
>
> -s, --silent
>
> Silent or quiet mode. Don't show progress meter or error messages.
>   Makes Curl mute. It will still output the data you ask for,
>   potentially even to the terminal/stdout unless you redirect it.
>
> Use -S, --show-error in addition to this option to disable progress
>   meter but still show error messages.

`-s`は通常出力される進捗状況表示、それにエラーメッセージ表示を抑制する、ただし`-S`を同時に指定することでエラーメッセージの表示抑制は行わない、
要するにエラーメッセージ以外の出力を抑制する、というオプションです。